# VirtualStringTree - Outside controls not passing TDragObject

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

When dragging from a control onto the VirtualStringTree if the control has a TDragObject it is expected to use this as the Source in OnDragDrop and OnDragOver but it always returns the component. I believe this is a bug, but is there an alternate way of receiving another control's TDragObject without hacking TBaseVirtualTree?

```
procedure TIntelligenceCentralFrame.vstDragOver(Sender: 
  TBaseVirtualTree; Source: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; State: TDragState; 
  Pt: TPoint; Mode: TDropMode; var Effect: Integer; var Accept: Boolean);
```

Edit: [Minimal Example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4c76xrm6m51orli/AACB8WNYAqj0xko7U2CCQBYea)

Comment: This works fine as far as I remember. `Source` returns the source `TDragObject` as expected. Could you provide a minimal compilable example ?

Comment: I've added a small example with source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior is correct. You have used [`TDragControlObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragControlObject) as a drag object and this one should pass the assigned control to [`OnDragOver`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnDragOver) and [`OnDragDrop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnDragDrop) events. Reference describes that as:

> When TDragControlObject is used, the OnDragOver and OnDragDrop events
>   receive the control being dragged as the Sender, instead of the drag
>   object itself.

Where `Sender` is the `Source` parameter of the virtual tree view's `OnDragOver` and `OnDragDrop` events. Solution is simple, use a different drag object. Or expect that you will get passed the assigned control when using the [`TDragControlObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragControlObject) drag object.

Comment: Much appreciated. The example that I provided as well as past code in our product were both always coming from TDragControlObject and I had assumed this must have always been an issue. Thanks again.